# Make a sphere move in the line renderer between two points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a line renderer component that is drawn between two gameObjects. How do I create a sphere that travels between these two gameObjects? For example, is starts at Point A and travels till Point B and then it returns from Point B to Point A.

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PointA;
    public GameObject PointB;
    public float lineWidth;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;


    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.SetWidth(lineWidth,lineWidth);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, PointA.transform.localPosition);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, PointB.transform.localPosition);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject PointA;
    public GameObject PointB;
    public float lineWidth;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    GameObject sphere;
    public float speedOfSphere = 1f;
    public float TimeToStart;
    private bool StartAhead = true;
    public Material SphereMaterial;
    public Material LineRendererMaterial;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.SetWidth(lineWidth, lineWidth);
        sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, PointA.transform.localPosition);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, PointB.transform.localPosition);
        lineRenderer.material = LineRendererMaterial;

        sphere.transform.position = PointA.transform.position;
        sphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = SphereMaterial;

        while (true)
        {
            if(StartAhead==true)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeToStart);
                StartAhead = false;
            }

            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(sphere.transform, PointA.transform.position, PointB.transform.position, speedOfSphere));
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(sphere.transform, PointB.transform.position, PointA.transform.position, speedOfSphere));
        }

    }


    IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        var i = 0.0f;
        var rate = 1.0f / time;
        while (i < 1.0f)
        {
            i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Just added a while loop at the start with Coroutine that works in an infinite loop.